# Share WiFi Over WiFi

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I have 2 WiFi adapters on my laptop (internal + external -Alfa -) how can I share the alfa wifi ?
I mean I don't have Ethernet connection so I want to share the connection that I have on the alfa over the internal adapter.
I tried connectify but I couldn't get internet connection using the new created WiFi, same for other programs.

Comment: Here have a look at this discussion http://superuser.com/questions/520484/use-2-wireless-adapters-to-connect-to-2-wifi-networks-local-and-internet-simul which may get you with some idea.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  But i guess that discussion was about using 2 adapters simultaneously to connect the same lapotop. In my case i want to share the wifi.on alfa using the internal adapter. I want to share it with my phone.

Comment: Any reason you want to share connections through your laptop and not have others connect directly to the external? You could quickly bottleneck connections using your laptop like that.

Comment: An Android phone? You could share your PCs Internet connection with the phone via Internet pass through, aka "reverse tethering." It would be wired connection but it sounds like it might meet your needs here. Another option would be setting up a Bluetooth personal area network or PAN. This would be wireless but also much slower than a wired pass through setup.

Comment: @MaQleod  because my phone adapter cannot get a good signal as Alfa does.

Comment: @PFitz I'll try it :)