# Can I connect to two networks simultaneously (but not bridge them) in Windows 10 if I have two network adapters?

Tags: networking, network-adapter

Perhaps this is a novice question, but:

I am dealing with two LANs: LAN 1 is a wired Ethernet connection to a small test network that is not connected to the internet (this is forbidden), used for monitoring a handful of connected devices. LAN 2 is also wired Ethernet through my dock, through which I have an internet connection. Each connection has its own network adapter.

Right now I use batch files to disable one adapter and enable the other adapter and then assign an IP when I want to switch networks. This is clunky, because if I'm connected to the test network and I need to quickly google something, I have to switch adapters, which takes ~1 minute or so round trip, and this downtime is really starting to add up.

Is there a way I can stay connected to both LANs without having to disable and reenable network adapters?

EDIT

Route print output

```
===========================================================================
Interface List
  4...b4 b6 86 13 a3 2d ......Intel(R) Ethernet Connection (2) I219-LM
 21...b4 b6 86 11 08 b6 ......Broadcom NetXtreme Gigabit Ethernet
  8...02 00 4c 4f 4f 50 ......Npcap Loopback Adapter
  1...........................Software Loopback Interface 1
  5...00 00 00 00 00 00 00 e0 Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter
===========================================================================

IPv4 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
Network Destination        Netmask          Gateway       Interface  Metric
          0.0.0.0          0.0.0.0     192.168.73.1    192.168.73.12     25
        127.0.0.0        255.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        127.0.0.1  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  127.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
      169.254.0.0      255.255.0.0         On-link   169.254.193.106    281
  169.254.193.106  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.193.106    281
  169.254.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.193.106    281
     192.168.73.0    255.255.255.0         On-link     192.168.73.12    281
    192.168.73.12  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.73.12    281
   192.168.73.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.73.12    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link   169.254.193.106    281
        224.0.0.0        240.0.0.0         On-link     192.168.73.12    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link         127.0.0.1    331
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link   169.254.193.106    281
  255.255.255.255  255.255.255.255         On-link     192.168.73.12    281
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None

IPv6 Route Table
===========================================================================
Active Routes:
 If Metric Network Destination      Gateway
  1    331 ::1/128                  On-link
  8    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    281 fe80::/64                On-link
 21    281 fe80::acc6:fefc:a192:7ccc/128
                                    On-link
  8    281 fe80::dc9f:2ff3:4c6f:c16a/128
                                    On-link
  1    331 ff00::/8                 On-link
  8    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
 21    281 ff00::/8                 On-link
===========================================================================
Persistent Routes:
  None
```

Comment: Similar question here but answer is the same, you must bridge the 2 adapters>>>>https://superuser.com/questions/520484/use-2-wireless-adapters-to-connect-to-2-wifi-networks-local-and-internet-simul

Comment: @Moab, Thanks. If I don't want to bridge these networks together because I don't want the test network attached to the internet in any way, I'm out of luck?

Comment: Servers use multiple network adapters all the time and they are segregated but don't know how they are set up, but is possible im sure. Hopefully someone more knowledgeable will speak yp.

Answer (score 2):

Windows will use two networks. You need to ensure:

- Each network uses a distinct set of IP addresses.
- Ensure that there is no default route to the test network by using the
  `route delete` command on its `0.0.0.0` route.
- Refer to computers by their IP addresses (beware of this Windows
  [gotcha](https://superuser.com/a/1543690/8672)).

Comment: Do I need to be attached to a specific network adapter only when I delete this route? If I am connected to the test network, the route command says that the route does not exist; if I delete the route when connected to the internet-connected LAN, I lose connection to the internet.

Comment: Please connect to both networks and add to your post the output of `route print`, so I can understand more.

Comment: Added route print output.

Comment: Seems fine. I guess `192.168.73.x` is the main network and `169.254.193.x` is the test network. What is the problem of using both via IP addresses?

Comment: No, the test network is 10.0.x.x, but whenever I am connected to the internet through apparently 192.168.73.x, the network setting screen puts a red X over the test network adapter. I cannot get them to be on/show up at the same time.

Comment: Try to install the latest drivers, for the Intel I219-LM [here](https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/82185/Intel-Ethernet-Connection-I219-LM). For the Broadcom you may try on their site with the exact model number. Another try is to delete it in Device Manager and reboot for Windows to install its own driver.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can stay connected to both LANs without having to disable and reenable network adapters. You can use a virtual private network (VPN) to connect to the test network. This will allow you to access both networks at the same time, without having to manually switch between adapters.

In order to create a virtual private network (VPN) to connect to the test network, you will need a VPN client software. There are many available on the internet, both free and paid. Once you have chosen a VPN client, you will need to set up the VPN connection on your computer. This will involve entering the server address, username, and password for the test network, as well as choosing the authentication method. After this, you will be able to connect to the test network and access both networks simultaneously.

Hope this helps.

Comment: No reason to believe there is a VPN server available to connect to. Regardless, the basic question  has not been answered as VPN or dirrect connection would both need to be resolved via the second adapter.  How would connecting to a VPN change anything relaterd to the question?    Please [edit](https://superuser.com/posts/1763856/edit) to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in [the help center](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).